# Why are my hex strings exactly the same on the server. But are different objects when deserialized

Tags: c#, sql-server, serialization

After serializing a object in C# I upload it to my database, each of the hex strings look like this:

```
0x0001000000FFFFFFFF01000000000000000C0200000046496E76656E746F72794F626A6563742C2056657273696F6E3D312E302E302E302C2043756C747572653D6E65757472616C2C205075626C69634B6579546F6B656E3D6E756C6C050100000019496E76656E746F72792E496E76656E746F72794F626A65637404000000
```

I was expecting each of the objects to be the same (meaning a error in my code) when I deserialized .But they are not, instead they represent the correct unique objects.

Is there some kind of pointer association happening in sql server?

Serialize method:

```
public  byte[] serialize()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, this); //NOTE: this refers to a InventoryObject
    byte[] returnVal = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Close();
    return returnVal;
}
```

Deserialize method:

```
    public static InventoryObject deserialize(byte[] arrBytes)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
        memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        InventoryObject obj = (Object)binForm.Deserialize(memStream) as InventoryObject;

        return obj ;
    }
```

Comment: Are the property values of your 2 objects different before you serialize them?

Comment: What do you mean by "different objects"? What type of check are you using to determine that they are different?

Comment: @ioSamurai I was examining the objects in the debugger.

Comment: @David Yes they are I examined them in the debugger. I have figured the issue out though thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. SQL server 2000 does not show the entire hex string to you in the query analyzer if it is greater than a certain length. Thus my hex strings are actually different.